# Laravel 5 manage big controllers in projects

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller that can contain up to 2k lines of code and so many custom methods. Now I want to make this controller more readable and better, so I read somewhere it's best pratice just to use main methods in my controller like below:

```
public function index() {
.
.
.
}

public function store(){
.
.
.
}
```

Now my question is that, if I keep these main functions in the controller, what should I do with the other methods and where should I store them to make them more readable and make more space for future methods?

Comment: use repository pattern.. also use pattern "slim controller fat model".

Comment: Tidied up code layout and typos.